# Reading NMEA data from iPhone GPS receiver

Tags: iphone, gps, nmea

I am looking for a way to get NMEA data from the builtin gps receiver of a iPhone.

Is there a way to access this data without using `CLLocationFramework`?

Answer (score 1):

NO, apple does not allow you to acces the GPS in an other way then via the CoreLocation Framework.

This also means that device without an GRPS chip can support location (it will use triangulation via WiFi).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to forge your own `$GPGGA` sentence based in information that can be retrieved from `CLLocationFramework`. Obviously you won't be able to set then number of satellites and HDOPs value will be approximated. If you must have NMEA0183 sentences, you could create them yourself.